# How to scope correct data in angularfire | firebase | angular | ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm working on an android game, im using ionic and firebase. I fixed the login: if the user logs in, it checks if the user exists and if not it creates an account.

Now I got a problem scoping the correct data in my controller. I can scope it in html using

```
{{ user.level }}
```

I can add data using

```
   users.child($scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id).set({

                Username: $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id

    });
```

i can update data using

```
user.update({
  "level": "Over 9000"
});
```

But when I try to scope it in my controller it keeps saying undefined or giving me wrong formatted data. (or says user not defined)

```
var level = user.level;
console.log(level);
```

my code is

```
    var app = angular.module('starter.controllers', ["firebase"])

  //page controller
app.factory("credentials", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var FIREB = new Firebase("https://sudokidsapp.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(FIREB);
  }
]);
app.controller('HomeScreen', function($scope, credentials, $state, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
  credentials.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $scope.authData = authData;
  });

  $scope.googlelogin = function() {
    credentials.$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData) {

          var users = new Firebase("https://sudokidsapp.firebaseio.com/users");
          $scope.users = $firebaseArray(users);

          var userId = $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id;
          checkIfUserExists(userId);

          function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
            var usersRef = new Firebase("https://sudokidsapp.firebaseio.com/users");
            usersRef.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
              var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
              userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
            });
          }

          function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
            if (exists) {
              currentUser = $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id;
              $state.go('app.next');
            } else {
              $scope.date = JSON.stringify(new Date());
              users.child($scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id).set({

                Username: $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.id,
                Gender: $scope.authData.google.cachedUserProfile.gender || "",
                level: 0,
                tutorial: true,
                world1: true,
                world2: false,
                world3: false,
                world4: false,
                world5: false,
                stickerset1: true,
                stickerset2: false,
                stickerset3: false,
                stickerset4: false,
                stickerset5: false,
                character: "none",
                date: $scope.date

              });
              $state.go('app.tutorial');

                }
              }


        }).catch(function(error) {

        });
      }

    });
app.controller("NextControllers", function($scope, $state, credentials, currentUser, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {


        var user = currentUser.google.id;
        var information = new Firebase("https://sudokidsapp.firebaseio.com/users/" + user);  
        $scope.information = $firebaseObject(information);
        console.log($scope.information);

});
```

--edit--
Fixed my problem using data snapshot

```
        $scope.UpdateLevel = function(){
            information.once("value", function(snapshot) {
              var data = snapshot.val();
              console.log(data);
              console.log(data.level);
              console.log(data.world5);

              var newdata = data.level + 1 ;
                information.update({
                  "level" : newdata
                })
              });
           }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problem is without seeing a JSBin or a Plnkr. From what I can see, you're problem is with the way you're handling asynchronous data.

Comment: I tried recreating the problem as good as i can http://plnkr.co/edit/WJOKQvwQ9NOQjscxJsFs?p=preview

Comment: It worked for me, I saw the user log in the console. But the issue is what I had mentioned to you before. You are better of resolving async data in your controllers. You are using global variables to get around this, but this will cause you more trouble as you move foward. Please read this section: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers

Comment: I edited my plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/WJOKQvwQ9NOQjscxJsFs?p=preview ... i really apreciate your help. i love firebase and would love to get more out of it them im doing at the moment